# SQL Server Top 1 returns null, top 2 works

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Here is the code:

```
select z.id, z.name, z.duration, z.errors, z.warnings, m.message from
(
    select Id, TestName as Name, Duration, isnull(Errors,0) as Errors, isnull(Warnings,0) as Warnings from 
    (
        select a.id as ID, a.Duration, b.TestName from
        (       
            select * from dbo.test where runid = 20902 and InstrumentUniqueId = 2
        ) as a
            join dbo.testinfo as b  
            on a.testinfoid = b.id      
    ) as x
    left outer join
    (
        select testid,
            sum(case when te.levelid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Errors,
            sum(case when te.levelid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Warnings
        from dbo.testevent te
        group by testid
    ) as y
    on x.ID = y.testid
) as z
left outer join 
(
    select top (1) message, testid from dbo.testevent where levelid = 1 
) as m
on z.id = m.testid
ORDER BY ID
```

For the `select top (1) message, testid from dbo.testevent where levelid = 1` nothing gets returned in the message field, however when I change it to `top (2)` the first message correctly shows.

Also, if I run `select top (1) message, testid from dbo.testevent where levelid = 1` individually outside the massive join, it returns the same result as using `top (2)` inside the big join.

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: top (1) without order is nonsense

Comment: Well, you're `top`ing first, and then joining on that. The only way this would ever work is if the *first* row returned from the subquery was one where `m.testid = z.id` (and yes, note as Giorgi said that you really want to use explicit ordering whenever using constructs such as `top`). Since your only filter is based on `levelid`, it'd be quite surprising if the single row returned would just randomly happened to be the right one...

Comment: Your last join (to "m") would be better re-written as a subquery in your select list.

Comment: Your doing a `left join`.  Sometimes there will be no match.  If you always want a match, switch to an inner join.